# Is it a way to cancel tp/sl with BiByt API

Tags: bybit, python-bybit

In the ByBit API, you can easily create TP/SL: https://bybit-exchange.github.io/docs/v5/position/trading-stop

But can it be removed?

I've come to the problems that there can only be 20 TP/SL a time, but I need to rearrange them, so it would be great if I could rearrange some of them.

I searched all the documentation, but there was nothing about it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Creating TP/SL orders using `trading-stop` doesn't provide orderId, so when you don't have orderId you can't cancel it through their `cancel order` api.

You can cancel the TP/SL order using [trading-stop](https://bybit-exchange.github.io/docs/v5/position/trading-stop) API, just pass `takeProfit='0' 'stopLoss='0'`

> takeProfit: Cannot be less than 0, 0 means cancel TP.
>
> stopLoss: Cannot be less than 0, 0 means cancel SL